How correctly use writePNG in PyMuPDF to extract images?
Trying to extract images and text with PyMuPDF but receive an error at the last line.
Followed this tutorial
https://invidious.reallyaweso.me/watch?v=QCasePBJxVI
error:
 line 26, in <module>
    pix.writePNG(f'image_Page{pageNumber}_{imgNumber}.png')
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^
AttributeError: 'Pixmap' object has no attribute 'writePNG'. Did you mean: '_writeIMG'?

script:
import fitz

file = fitz.open("file.pdf")

# extract text
for pageNumber, page in enumerate(file.pages(), start = 1):
    text = page.get_text()
    txt = open(f'report_Page_{pageNumber}.txt', 'a')
    txt.writelines(text)
    txt.close()

# extract images
for pageNumber, page in enumerate(file.pages(), start = 1):
    # replaced
    # for imgNumber, img in enumerate(page.getImageList(), start = 1):
    for imgNumber, img in enumerate(page.get_images(), start = 1):
        xref = img[0]
        pix = fitz.Pixmap(file, xref)

        if pix.n < 4:
            pix = fitz.Pixmap(fitz.csRGB, pix)

        # incorrect 
        # pix.writePNG(f'image_Page{pageNumber}_{imgNumber}.png')
        # update - solved
        pix.writePNG(f'image_Page{pageNumber}_{imgNumber}.png')



Outputting a Pixmap (PyMuPDF's internal image format) to a normal image file is a method with a different name: since many, many versions, you should use pix.save("image.png"). Please always consult PyMuPDF's excellent documentation before assuming an error! https://pymupdf.readthedocs.io/en/latest/pixmap.html#Pixmap.save
